# model vs session - which one to use for java application for storing data?

Tags: java, session, model-view-controller, model

Recently I attended an interview where I was asked this question

> How will you decide whether to use Model or Session to hold or pass data within the application?

I could not answer this question as my understanding in this regard in completely zero. 
Later I searched a lot and came across several articles which showed use of @Modelattribute and @Sessionattribute and their usage. 
But I want to know basically how to choose between usage of Model and Session? what is the difference between storing in a session and adding it in a model? 
Is there any relationship between setting in a session and setting in a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in model-view-controller, you would typically store **model attributes** inside the controller. You would then be able to retrieve these attributes in the view layer (JSP or some other view-rendering technology). But these attributes usually only live for the duration of the HTTP request. After the view is rendered and presented to the user, we do not have these model attributes anymore.

On the other hand, session attributes live for the duration of a user's session.

So to answer your question with an example...

Suppose we had a controller that was responsible for displaying items for sale on a website.

When a user requests a page, the controller would:

1. Query the database and find all of the items that match the user's criteria
2. Add the items to the model and return a view
3. Inside the view (JSP), we can retrieve the model and display the model attributes along with HTML/CSS to render the page that the user sees

On the other hand...what if we had information that needed to be presented throughout the lifetime of the user's session? Like the total cost of all the items in their shopping cart? We should store that as a session attribute so we could access it and display it on every HTTP request

Comment: Thank you @Solace....your answer helped me to understand why this question was asked to me. But I have one doubt. While searching for the answer, I came across many articles where it was mentioned "NOT TO USE SESSION" or "USE SESSION WHEN IT IS BADLY REQUIRED". Why it is said so I did not understand though.....Also is there any way that we can manipulate model to hold data across a Session? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think there is something inherently wrong with session attributes. Obviously if something should be request-scoped, then add it to the model instead. I do not think there is a way to keep model attributes throughout the session, but you can keep them after a redirect with flash attributes